# Check if an image exists on cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a project in CakePHP and I would like to know how to check if an image exists with the extension '.jpg' if not use the extension '.JPG', any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bool file_exists ( string $filename )

Checks whether a file or directory exists. Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'file123.jpg';
```

Comment: Could you please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

my image path like app/webroot/img/upload/file123.jpg

WWW_ROOT define your webroot folder path and DS define '/'

```
$image='file123.jpg';
$file = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $image;
```

if conditions for file check

```
if(file_exists($file) && $image){
 enter your code if file exists
 }else{
 file not exists
}
```